# What API parses Browser Definition File Schema files in .NET?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, browser-detection, logfiles, 51degrees

I have some IIS logs with header information I'd like to be parsed by pre-existing frameworks.  Can I leverage the part of ASP.NET that uses [Browser Definition Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228122.aspx) perhaps in tandem with the [51 Degrees mobi](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/12/17/using-51degreesmobi-foundation-for-accurate-mobile-browser-detection-on-aspnet-mvc-3/) tools.

What is the right .NET API (or similar) that I should use to analyze log files?

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing some open source work for 51Degrees at the moment. I wrote an article recently about parsing W3C log files using the C implementation of the API. You can find the article [here](http://51degrees.mobi/Support/Blogs/tabid/212/EntryId/67/Gaining-Device-Statistics-from-W3C-Server-Logs.aspx?CATReferrer=1765). Is this the kind of thing you were looking for? Hope this helps.